# jqplot: If I have two pie plots, can I make so that each wedge with the same label have the same color?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqplot

If I have two pie plots, Is it possible to have each wedge with the same label have the same color? I used to be able to do this with JFreeChart (I can specify color for each label, so I put `<label, color>` inside a map, and as I loop through each label, I can determine the color of that label), but when I switch to JQPlot, it is not obvious to me how I can accomplish this. Is it possible to accomplish this in JQPlot? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is `seriesColors: [ "#95268D", "#F5F5F5"]`

You can define the colors however you like, just match the series up so that pie1 series1 is the same color as pie2 series1.

[Series colors](http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/jqplot-core-js.html#jqPlot.seriesColors)

Comment: This will be a bit difficult. Your solution is based on the order, but there are many things that can cause the order to not be the same. First the label will not always come back in the same order for every chart. Second, sometimes one pie chart will not have somes of the labels compare to the other pie chart, this will screw up the order. Note how I state that I use Map<label, color> to accomplish this in JFreeChart, this way I dont depend on the order

Answer (score 0):

Each series can have a `label` and `color` associated with them:

> An individual data series object.  Cannot be instantiated directly,
>   but created by the Plot oject.  Series properties can be set or
>   overriden by the options passed in from the user.
>
> Properties will be assigned from a series array at the top level of
>   the options.  If you had two series and wanted to change the color and
>   line width of the first and set the second to use the secondary y axis
>   with no shadow and supply custom labels for each:

```
{
   series:[
       {color: '#ff4466', lineWidth: 5, label:'good line'},
       {yaxis: 'y2axis', shadow: false, label:'bad line'}
   ]
}
```

Here are the [Series Properties](http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/jqplot-core-js.html#Series).